# Сравнить две логические переменные при помощи операторов "<", ">"

Tags: java, java-stream

Мне нужно реализовать вывод на экран только тех элементов коллекции, у которых цитата:

> значение поля speaking которых больше заданного

где `speaking` - логическая переменная, и магическое "заданное" - тоже значение логической переменной, но уже введённое пользователем. Другими словами, нужно реализовать операторы ">" и "<", но для boolean переменных.

Звучит глупо, но таково задание. Так что, нужно как-то сделать.

Максимум, на что меня хватило - это написать вот такой код:

```
List<Dragon> list = new ArrayList<>(collectionManager.getCollection());
list = list.stream().filter(o-> o.getSpeaking().equals(Boolean.valueOf(arg))).toList();
```

Но так я получаю только объекты, у которых speaking равен введённому, а не меньше/больше.
Прошу помощи и благодарю за потраченное время.

**P.S.** Стоит, наверное, разъяснить какие результаты ожидаются от кода. Насколько я понял, если пользователь введёт `true`, то программа должна ничего не выводить. Если `false` - выводить только объекты у которых значение поля `speaking` `true`. Вообще, нужна ещё функция с обратным действием(поменять в предыдущих предложениях `true` и `false` местами), но там я уже сам на примере разобраться смогу.

Comment: Я бы всё таки уточнил у автора

Comment: @AlexeyTen Автор - автоматическая система для генерации вариантов лабораторных работ университета

Comment: Ну для этого преподаватель существует

Comment: @AlexeyTen До каникул спрашивал - ответили что-то в духе "барахтайся как хочешь"

Comment: Хотя я конечно не понимаю у чём сложность ввести отношение порядка на множестве из двух элементов…

Comment: @AlexeyTen А можно поподробнее, что такое отношение порядка?

Comment: "отношение порядка" - штука примером которой является операция `<`. Заводите функцию, которая для каждой пары значений возвращает истину, когда первое значение меньше второго, и ложь иначе. У вас всего два значения, четыре комбинации, отношение порядка вы уже определили в конце вопроса. Осталось придать ему форму в виде кода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из вашего P.S. получается такой псевдокод:

```
if arg:
    do nothing
else:
    if o.speaking:
         print o
```

Шаг 1:

```
if not arg:
    if o.speaking:
         print o
```

Шаг 2:

```
if not arg and o.speaking:
    print o
```

На языке Java:

```
List<Dragon> list = new ArrayList<>(collectionManager.getCollection());
list = list.stream().filter(o -> !Boolean.valueOf(arg) && o.getSpeaking()).toList();
```

Comment: Вы просто открыли мне глаза. Это же просто обычный XOR от поля объекта и самой функции(больше=true, меньше=false)!

Comment: Всё-так не XOR. У XOR оба аргумента равноправны. Здесь нет.

Comment: Да, согласен. Но сходство всё же есть